# Export canvas to image?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, canvas, http-headers

I'm making a facebook app. It will get image of user from "https://graph.facebook.com/{fbid}/picture". Then I draw that image to a canvas.
It worked well. But when I export that canvas to base64 image, it return error:

> Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

I tried to set crossOrigin = "anonymous" for each image before draw it to canvas. Then it worked well with chrome browser.

But on safari, it return error:

> Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you retrieve image using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`?

Comment: But I don't know how to get image using XMLHttpRequest. Can you give me some suggestions. Thanks you!

Comment: This sounds like a safari bug, I'm pretty sure images from graph.facebook are sent with the correct allow cross origin header. Which version of safari is this?

Comment: My safari is on ios 9.2. But I don't think that is a safari bug. When I make client get fb image via my server, so I don't need to set crossOrigin anonymous for image, it worked well.